# Linking error with Gluon client maven plugin in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, visual-studio-2019, gluon

I'm trying to compile some examples for Gluon's client maven plugin, using x64 native tools for VS 2019. When I try to run mvn client:build,
I get a "linking failed" error, shown below:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'strictmath.lib'
```

Does anyone have a fix?

Comment: That lib has precisely been removed from GraalVM a few days ago. There is already a fix, but you'll need to use the 0.1.27-SNAPSHOT version of the Client plugin. See [this](https://github.com/gluonhq/client-maven-plugin/issues/176#issuecomment-637499189) on how to use it.

Comment: @JoséPereda That worked! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Good to know. There will be a new release soon with that fix.